# Run timer without thread in java

Tags: java, timertask

I am building simulator that run 1000(and more) clients, in each client i want to run task after X time, i tried `TimerTask`, the problem is that in each task(more than 1000) new thread is created.

Did there as any task timer without thread?

Comment: How many task you are running for each client ? 
Can you share the code snippet for this ?

Comment: Can't you use `Thread.sleep(X*1000)` just before invoking the main task part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can schedule multiple TimerTasks using a single Timer, they just can't run at the same time. Depending on your need, that may be good enough.

But, quoting the javadoc of [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html):

> Java 5.0 introduced the `java.util.concurrent` package and one of the concurrency utilities therein is the [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) which is a thread pool for repeatedly executing tasks at a given rate or delay. It is effectively a more versatile replacement for the `Timer`/`TimerTask` combination, as it allows multiple service threads, accepts various time units, and doesn't require subclassing `TimerTask` (just implement `Runnable`). Configuring `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` with one thread makes it equivalent to `Timer`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simulate 1000(and more) clients acting simultaneously, you have to use `Thread`s! Otherwise you would have a single Thread in which your definite logic specifies when what logic of what client is done - that really does not simulate the clients acting in parallel.

Comment: The answer of @Andreas seams to be quite helpful to minimize the amount of threads through *sharing* by a ThreadPool but it doesn't change my thinking that you have to use Threads directly or indirectly.